# Random string returned from API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to retrieve the request body from API Gateway proxy request. When I pass a body, I am getting a random string. The request works fine in Tests in API gateway but not in actual API

the request I got was

```
{
    "path": "/movie",
    "headers": {
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "none",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "postman-token": "e9f9216f-850d-1037-a2c9-d6a554f55813",
        "origin": "chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "Host": "8cfsbr5d62.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5ed9e7b8-94f205f0fed74580d6bb5bf0",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "49.206.4.254",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty"
    },
    "resource": "/movie",
    "queryStringParameters": {
        "movie": "ddk"
    },
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "body": "ewoJIm1vdmllIjoiZ3BwIgp9"
}
```

Comment: One thing I could decipher is that body is coming in base64 format. I tried decoding it and got the body I was trying to send

Answer (score 1):

It is **base64 encoded**:

```
base64 -d <<< ewoJIm1vdmllIjoiZ3BwIgp9
{
    "movie":"gpp"
}
```

Thus you have to **decode it** in your lambda.

You can get more info about API gateway encoding/decoding into base64:

- [Content type conversions in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had Binary Media Types configuration as '*/*' since one of the API had image payload. But that configuration affected JSON payload as well and the API started encoding any request body to encoded string. My case the string was not actually random one, it was Base 64 encoded String.

Two options:

1) If you want to keep generic Binary Media Type, then decode the Base64 string in Lambda

2) Keep specific Binary Media Type in API gateway settings ex. image/*

Answer (score 0):

I did accidentally deploy api gateway with:

```
BinaryMediaTypes:
  - '*~1*'
```

...and noticed the request body to be base64. In the API I was working with it was unnecessary and I removed it.

However it stays in AWS console, post request body is sill base64 even that I remove BinaryMediaTypes in AWS console.

I had to remove and re-deploy the whole stack to get rid of this